# Notice: Undefined variable: tmp_name in C:

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Buen día Amigos StackOverflow

Tengo el siguiente error al guardar un formulario con una imagen, el error que recibo:

[image: Notice: Undefined variable: tmp_name in C:]

> \xampp\htdocs\stock\ajax\nueva_categoria.php on line 20
>   El catalogo ha sido ingresada satisfactoriamente.

Quiero guardar la imagen en una carpeta del servidor y en la BD quiero guardar la ruta. En la tabla html me muestra la ruta de la imagen, pero no guarda la imagen en la carpeta.

Este es el código:

nueva_categoria.php

```
<?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/

if(empty($_POST['nombre'])) {
       $errors[] = "Nombre vacío";  
    } else if (!empty($_POST['nombre'])){
    /* Connect To Database*/
    require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code


    $nombre=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["nombre"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $descripcion=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["descripcion"],ENT_QUOTES)));                  
    $date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $foto=isset($_FILES["foto"]);
        if ($foto["type"] == "img/jpg" OR $foto["type"] == "img/jpeg" );
            $ruta = "../img".md5($foto["tmp_name"]).".jpg"; 
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $ruta);  

    $sql="INSERT INTO categorias (foto, nombre_categoria, descripcion_categoria,date_added) VALUES ('$ruta','$nombre','$descripcion','$date_added')";
    $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if ($query_new_insert){

            echo "El catalogo ha sido ingresada satisfactoriamente.";
        } else{
            $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
        }
    } else {
        $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
    }



    if (isset($errors)){

        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Error!</strong> 
                <?php
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo $error;
                        }

                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        if (isset($messages)){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                echo $message;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

?>
```

El archivo del formulario

registro_categorias.php

```
    <?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="nuevoCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Agregar nuevo catalogo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guardar_categoria" name="guardar_categoria" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="foto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Foto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" class="form-control" id="foto" name="foto">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Descripción</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion"   maxlength="255" ></textarea>

            </div>
          </div>







      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos">Guardar datos</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Y este es el archivo js que tiene el AJAX:

```
$( "#guardar_categoria" ).submit(function(event){
    $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true); 

var datos = new FormData($("#guardar_categoria")[0])
$("resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...")
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/nueva_categoria.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: datos,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
        $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
        load(1);
    }
});
event.preventDefault()
})
```

Adjunto imagen del error y en el fondo se puede ver que guarda la ruta y ahí quiero ver la imagen.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: la variable `$tmp_name` está sin definir... `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $ruta);`

Comment: Si ese es el error pero la debo definir en: $foto=isset($_FILES["foto"]); quedando asi: $foto=isset($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"]); o donde se define voy a probar

Comment: defini la variable y ya no genera error pero no guarda la imagen en la carpeta img del servidor que esta por fuera de la carpeta donde se encuentra nueva_categoria.php. El codigo quedo asi: 
  $descripcion=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["descripcion"],ENT_QUOTES)));             
  $date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $foto=isset($_FILES["foto"]);
  $tmp_name = $foto["tmp_name"];
   if ($foto["type"] == "img/jpg" OR $foto["type"] == "img/jpeg" );
    $ruta = "img/" .md5($foto["tmp_name"]).".jpg"; 
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $ruta);

Comment: te falta separar el dirrectorio img con el nombre de la imagen